# Strange values in an int array instance variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory-management, int, instance-variables

I looked for similar topics but no luck so far, so here it goes:

In an Objective-C class I declared an `int` pointer instance variable to hold an  array of `int`:

```c
@interface MyList : NSObject {
    int index;      // A simple int to hold an index reference
    NSString *name; // The name of the list
    int *bookList;  // A pointer to an int array that holds a list of numbers
}

@property (nonatomic) int index;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int *bookList;

@end
```

I tested this as follows and **all** data contained in the instance variables was correctly stored and displayed by the `NSLog` statements:

```c
MyList *aList = [[MyList alloc] init];
[aList setIndex:1];
[aList setName:@"ListOne"];
[aList setBookList:(int []){1, 2, 3, 0}];

NSLog(@"Show MyList object's data after object is populated");
NSLog(@"[%d]: %@", aList.index, aList.name);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    NSLog(@"bookList[%d] = %d", i, aList.bookList[i]);
}
```

*However*, when I send this object as an argument to a method and I try to print the contents of the `int` array, I get strange numbers, and the same happens after returning from the method:

```c
-(void)displayMyList:(MyList *)theList {
    NSLog(@"Show MyList object's data in displayMyList method");
    NSLog(@"[%d]: %@", theList.index, theList.name);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        NSLog(@"bookList[%d] = %d", i, theList.bookList[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my test code, as the values of the `index` and `name` instance variables don't get changed when the object is sent to the `displayMyList:` method. I debugged step-by-step and the pointer to the `int` array points to the same address all the time, so it seems there's a side-effect somewhere that's changing the array's values, or I'm not getting how memory is placed for this type of pointers to `int` arrays. Maybe it's just some pointer arithmetic I'm not getting right, because I haven't seen this in any of the iPhone programming books I have.

I wanted to implement the `int` array because the math I do with it is really simple and it seemed using an `NSArray` was overkill (if this approach doesn't work I can always go with an `NSArray`, though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
[aList setBookList:(int[]){1,2,3,0}];
```

The scope of a stack-allocated reference is limited only to the surrounding function, that's why you're getting garbage values in a different scope, because the stack in which it was allocated is no longer in use.

You need to `malloc` this list of `int`s to push this reference onto the heap, like so:

```
int sourceList[] = { 1, 2, 3, 0 }; 
int *bookList = malloc(sizeof sourceList); 

memcpy(aList->bookList, sourceList, sizeof sourceList);
```

Since you called `malloc`, you must eventually relinquish the memory occupied by the "array" by calling `free` in your `-dealloc` method.

As an alternative, you could use an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects, like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *bookList;

//...

#define NUMINT(x) [NSNumber numberWithInt:x]

NSArray *bookList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NUMINT(1), NUMINT(2), NUMINT(3), NUMINT(0), nil];
[aList setBookList:bookList];
```

Comment: Easier: int sourceList[] = { 1, 2, 3, 0 };  int *bookList = malloc(sizeof sourceList); memcpy(bookList, sourceList, sizeof sourceList);

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation and the code snippets. I plan to use the arrays for the whole existence of the application, so my next question is: do I have to `free` the memory occupied by the array  in my `dealloc` method or will it be relinquished when the app quits?

Comment: @rtovars The memory will be relinquished on app exit.

Answer (score 1):

The array that you're creating when you assign it is local to that method; the memory gets re-used after the method ends, which means that there are basically garbage values ending up there. The pointer itself doesn't change because it's an ivar, and the address it points to doesn't change because you haven't reassigned it. Only the contents of the pointed-to address change.

You'll need to manage the memory yourself if you want it to stick around for the life of your object. This isn't too big a deal, assuming that you won't need to hand off the array to any other object.* There's no need to switch to an `NSArray` if you already have logic using `int`s.

```
// Get the memory
// malloc returns a generic C pointer, void *, so the value needs to be
// cast to make the compiler happy. 
int * arr = (int *)malloc(LEN_OF_BOOKLIST * sizeof(int));
// Fill in values
//...
// Assign to the ivar
[aList setBookList:arr];
```

Then you need to free that memory when the object is destroyed:

```
- (void) dealloc {

    free(bookList);
    // Clean up other ivars
    [super dealloc];
}
```

In all, this is very like manually handling the memory of any old object. You call `malloc` (with an argument stating the amount of memory you want) instead of sending `alloc` to the class (which knows how much memory is needed), and use `free` instead of `release` to relinquish the memory. (Also note that `free`, since there is no reference counting, immediately marks the memory for re-use.)

*Which is essentially why reference counting was invented.

Comment: Note that it is also exceedingly uncommon to be managing a raw int* array in an Objective-C class.   Typically, it'll either be a fixed length array *or* an ObjC collection class.   One might also consider creating a wrapper class that wraps the C array of goop for convenience's sake.

Comment: A wrapper class in this case might be an excellent idea. Seems a shame to have to go through the `NSNumber` boxing-unboxing routine. That's probably my least favorite part of ObjC.

Comment: @bbum Thanks for the clarification, as a matter of fact I was beginning to think my code looked suspicious. One question: Is this use of raw int* arrays sanctioned by Apple? As you can see I'm still learning the ropes of iOS development, and I haven't submitted anything yet to the AppStore, but I was wondering if this type of implementation would be a reason for Apple to reject my code. Is this something I should worry about?

Comment: Sanctioned?  Sure.   It is just C.  But recommended?  Not really-- there are certainly cases to do so, but they are pretty few and far between for the typical iOS app.  And, often, if you have to dip down to raw C for performance reasons, it is best to use C++ (as it is very good at abstraction in a performant matter).