# How to convert NSArray into NSString**

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an NSArray that contains objects of NSString.  I want to create an NSString ** object from those strings.

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];
NSString ** myStrings = ??? // an array of NSString*
```

Is there a non-malloc solution?  Can we allocate myStrings in the autorelease pool somehow, or obtain a handle to the objects property in myArray and use that?

Comment: have you taken a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962149/strange-values-in-an-int-array-instance-variable-in-objective-c ? the annoying part is gonna be the malloc/free which you probably not used to due to ARC

Comment: @luk2302 good reference, but I am looking for a non-malloc solution if one exists - I'll edit the question

Comment: There probably isn't one

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you using that requires a C array of NSStrings?

Comment: @Justin it was part of an online test I received - the return type is a NSString**

Comment: Did you really have to return an array of NSStrings or simply a NSString** which does not necessarily mean that you are going to use it as an array.

Comment: @luk2302 I had to return an array of NSString*, and the return type of the function was predeclared to NSString**

Comment: What confuses me further is that the calling function was shown to me and it did not deallocate the returned array after use, but it did have an explicit autorelease pool block.  So, not being an expert in Objective-C, I thought they're expecting me to return a non-malloced array that would be somehow autoreleased, otherwise there's a memory leak.  Hence the question I posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: You shouldn't do this.

That said, here is how you can create a C array of NSString pointers from an NSArray, backed by autoreleased memory:

```
NSArray * myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];
NSMutableData * myData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:(sizeof(NSString *) * myArray.count)];    
NSString ** myStrings = myData.mutableBytes;
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++) {
    myStrings[i] = myArray[i];
}
```

This is a *terrible* idea, from a memory management perspective.

Each `myStrings[i]` value will only be valid for so long as `myArray` is retained, and the value of `myStrings` will only be valid for so long as `myData` is retained.

Under ARC, the `myArray` and `myData` objects will be released as soon as they go out of scope, so `myStrings` will point to free'd memory as soon as it is returned from a method.

Comment: you're showing me here something I didn't know (NSMutableData).  There was an explicit autorelease pool block in the calling function, so my guess is that your solution is correct because they were not using ARC.